# How to copy two non adjacent columns in range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy just columns D & H and paste to a table. 
This is what i have so far.
I have tried a few different modifications searching this site with no luck.
Thanks

```
Sub Zulily_DS()
On Error Resume Next

Dim lastrowB As Long
Dim lastrowB1 As Long
Dim myLastCell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

lastrowB = Sheets("Source").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastrowB1 = Sheets("Source").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Source").Select
With Sheets("Zulily_DS")

If Sheets("Source").Range("C2").Value = vbNullString Then
    .Range("D2:H2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy _
                                                                            Sheets("Source").Cells(lastrowB1, 2)

ElseIf Sheets("Source").Range("C2").Value > "0" Then
    .Range("D2:H2", .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy _
                                                                            Sheets("Source").Cells(lastrowB, 2)
End If
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

If instead of separating your ranges like:

`Range("A1:A2","D1:D2")`

Change to:

`Range("A1:A2,D1:D2")`

Notice the quotes are not separating the ranges from each other. They will paste in a table format like you are expecting like this:

Instead of this:

`Range("A1:A2","D1:D2").Copy Range("B6:C7")`

Use This:

`Range("A1:A2,D1:D2").Copy Range("B6:C7")`

The first is copying different ranges, while the second is combining the ranges.

Comment: Your range `A1:A2,D1:D2` *will* be copied, but `A1:A2,D2:D3` - won't.

Comment: Figured it out by adding another line of code to to each If statement

Comment: .Range("H2", .Range("H" & 
    Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Copy _
          Sheets("Source").Cells(lastrowB1, 3)

Comment: @JohnyL This is only the method to adjust to the code to fix copying the ranges. if you run a simple test like `Range("A1:A2,D1:D2").Copy Range("B6:C7")` you will get the expected results.

Comment: @ARossi you code in the comments are suggesting you are copying the columns separately, but you can use the method I described to simplify to one line.